# Postgresql trigger syntax error at or near "NEW"

Tags: postgresql

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
ALTER TABLE publishroomcontacts ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS contactorder integer NOT NULL default 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION publishroomcontactorder() RETURNS trigger AS $publishroomcontacts$
    BEGIN   
      IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            with newcontactorder as (SELECT contactorder FROM publishroomcontacts WHERE publishroomid = NEW.publishroomid ORDER BY contactorder limit 1)    
            NEW.contactorder = (newcontactorder + 1);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$publishroomcontacts$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER publishroomcontacts BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON publishroomcontacts
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE publishroomcontactorder();
```

I've been looking into a lot of examples and they all look like this. Most of them a couple of years old tho. Has this changed or why doesn't NEW work? And do i have to do the insert in the function or does postgres do the insert with the returned NEW object after the function is done?

Comment: that approach is not going to work in a multiuser environment.

Comment: @Jasen is there a better approach for multiuser environment? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but your syntax is wrong here:

```
with newcontactorder as (SELECT contactorder FROM publishroomcontacts WHERE publishroomid = NEW.publishroomid ORDER BY contactorder limit 1)    
NEW.contactorder = (newcontactorder + 1);
```

Do not use CTE query if there is no select that comes afterwards. If you want to increment `contactorder` column for particular `publishroomid` whenever new one is being added and this is your sequence (auto increment) mechanism then you should replace it with:

```
NEW.contactorder = COALESCE((
    SELECT max(contactorder)
    FROM publishroomcontacts
    WHERE publishroomid = NEW.publishroomid
    ), 1);
```

Note the changes:

- there's no CTE, just variable assignment with SELECT query
- use `MAX()` aggregate function instead of `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT`
- wrapped up with `COALESCE(x,1)` function to properly insert first contacts for rooms, it will return `1` if your query does return `NULL`

**Your trigger should look like this**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION publishroomcontactorder() RETURNS trigger AS $publishroomcontacts$
BEGIN   
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    NEW.contactorder = COALESCE((
      SELECT max(contactorder) + 1
      FROM publishroomcontacts
      WHERE publishroomid = NEW.publishroomid
      ), 1);
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$publishroomcontacts$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Postgres** will insert the row itself, you don't have to do anything, because `RETURN NEW` does that.

*This solution does not take care of concurrent inserts which makes it unsafe for multi-user environment! You can work around this by performing an `UPSERT` !*

Comment: Great answer! Thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

`WITH` is not an assignment in PL/pgSQL.

PL/pgSQL interprets the line as SQL statement, but that is bad SQL because the `WITH` clause is followed by `NEW.contactorder` rather than `SELECT` or another CTE.

Hence the error; it has nothing to do with `NEW` as such.

You probably want something like

```
SELECT contactorder INTO newcontactorder
FROM publishroomcontacts
WHERE publishroomid = NEW.publishroomid
ORDER BY contactorder DESC  -- you want the biggest one, right?
LIMIT 1;
```

You'll have to declare `newcontactorder` in the `DECLARE` section.

**Warning:** If there are two concurrent inserts, they might end up with the same `newcontactorder`.

Comment: Good answer! Thx! :)